# Allowing xhost access to another user, permanently

Tags: permissions, x11, kde, gui, xhost

I want to run a GUI application as another user (say other-guy). Whenever I want to do so, I run

```
xhost si:localuser:other-guy
```

The changes only persist until a reboot. How do I make this permission permanent, so that I don't have to run this command ever again?

For reference, I run KDE with SDDM as the display manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE executes scripts from directory ~/.kde/Autostart/ when you login automatically.

So one of solutions would be to create a file there, change permissions of the file to executable and put the needed code inside:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n/usr/bin/xhost si:localuser:other-guy\n' > ~/.kde/Autostart/xhost.sh
chmod 700 ~/.kde/Autostart/xhost.sh
```

So ~/.kde/Autostart/xhost.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/xhost si:localuser:other-guy
```

and is executed right after you log into KDE automatically.

Comment: For some reason, my KDE Autostart directory was `~/.config/autostart`. Anyways, I put the script in there. I'll accept your answer after I reboot and test if it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I had to move the script to `~/.config/autostart-scripts` and then it showed up under Startup Applications in KDE Settings. That perfectly worked. Thanks!